# Gremlin hasId using property of parent

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I would like to filter `out` by an id. The value of the id is on a property of the parent. Example:

```
g.V('1234')
    .as('parent')
    .out()
        .has(id, parent.childId). <--- how do I get the parent id?
```

How would one approach this?

The closest I've been able to get is the following query, but it seems to ignore the `has` and simply returns all results of `out`.

```
g.V('123')
    .as('parent')
        .values('childId')
        .as('childIdValue')
    .select('parent')
        .out('hasChild')
        .has('id', select('childIdValue'))
```

**EDIT**

It works as expected when a vertex property other than the Id is used. Example:

```
g.V('123')
    .as('parent')
        .values('childId')
        .as('childIdValue')
    .select('parent')
        .out('hasChild')
        .has('childProp', select('childIdValue'))
```

I've tried all variations of `id` that I can think of. `'id'`, `id`, `id()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare an ID using a `where by` approach. For example something like:

```
where(eq('parent')).by('childProp').by('childId')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for introducing me to `where by`,